# will sendTransaction check function before broadcast to the network?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

If I have a function with precondition check at the beginning that uses only SLOAD, and I perform a sendTransaction on this function. Assuming the precondition check immediately failed and exit. Will the geth detect this and stop the broadcast? Or regardless it will broadcast to the network and cost me gas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify gas limit for your transaction, `geth` will try to estimate gas limit by executing your transaction locally.  As long as transaction execution fails, `geth` will not be able to estimate gas limit and thus will probably not send the transaction.

EDIT: I was wrong, `geth` will still send the transaction with some default gas limit.  So you need to estimate gas limit yourself.  More advanced clients, such as Mist, do this automatically and warn user in case he tries to send transaction that will probably fail.

```
> web3.eth.estimateGas ({from: web3.eth.accounts [0], to: "0x7265A4Af0eaC361cEd240474eBD47A0e7cE48392"});
Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> web3.eth.estimateGas ({from: web3.eth.accounts [0], to: "0x7265A4Af0eaC361cEd240474eBD47A0e7cE48393"});
21000
```

Answer (score 0):

The geth client will perform some basic checks, like the transaction is well formed the nonce is valid, etc. But it will not execute the transaction.

This means your transaction will be executed only when it is processed by a miner and you will have to pay the fee when the precondition fails.